# ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword Error

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_LOADMONEY
ON KIOSK
AFTER INSERT
AS
DECLARE @LOADEDCARDID INT
DECLARE @LOADEDAMOUNT INT

SELECT @LOADEDCARDID = LOADEDCARDID, @LOADEDAMOUNT = LOADEDAMOUNT FROM INSERTED
UPGRADE CARD SET CHARGE = CHARGE + @LOADEDAMOUNT
WHERE CARDID = @LOADEDCARDID
```

I run this code, but i am having an error which is "ORA-04071: missing BEFORE, AFTER or INSTEAD OF keyword". I have AFTER statement, i dont understand what is the problem.

Comment: Try placing "AFTER INSERT" before "ON KIOSK"

Comment: I tried what you recommend, but it gives "ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification" error.

Comment: [How about checking out the official Oracle documentation on CREATE TRIGGER?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm)

Comment: T-SQL and PL/SQL are not subject to the same ANSI which govern SQL.  Consequently they do things in *really* different ways.  You need to read the Oracle documentation instead of blindly writing SQL Server code and wondering why it doesn't compile in Oracle.

Answer (score 7):

You have used syntax is for sql server.

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_LOADMONEY
AFTER INSERT
ON KIOSK FOR EACH ROW
/*  
 These variables are not required because Oracle triggers can reference the table's
 columns directly using the :OLD and :NEW prefixes.   
 DECLARE 
     LOADEDCARDID PLS_INTEGER;
     LOADEDAMOUNT PLS_INTEGER;
*/
BEGIN
   UPDATE CARD 
      SET CHARGE = CHARGE + :NEW.LOADEDAMOUNT
    WHERE CARDID = :NEW.LOADEDCARDID;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But now i am getting that one :"ERROR at line 2: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
     form
   current cursor 1. CREATE TRIGGER TRG_LOADMONEY,2. AFTER INSERT,3. ON KIOSK,4. BEGIN". Any idea about that?

Comment: You correctly identified that the OP was using SQL Server but alas you didn't actually post code which use Oracle syntax.  I have fixed this.  You're welcome.  Merry Christmas!

Comment: @APC thank you very much, that really helped. Merry Chrismas.